# Redirect if page is blank

Tags: php, search, redirect, location

I'm working on some sort of search engine that adds on to a URL to complete the request. using header(Location:http://www.WEBSITENAME.com/'. $search); Although sometimes this will send me to a blank page. Was wondering if there's any sort of code that will redirect me to another page if that error happens. I want the else to be what it redirects to if the page is blank. Thanks.
My code: 

search.php

```
    <?php
     $search = $_POST["search"];
 if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    header('Location:http://cydia.saurik.com/package/'.$search);
}else{
    ?>
    <?php
    echo "
        <head>
            <style>
                #header{
                    color:black;
                }
                .header{
                    color:black;
                    font-size:25px;
                }
                #header_minor{
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
                .header_minor{
                    font-size:18px;
                }
                a[class='header_minor']{
                    color:black;
                }
                body{
                    text-align:center;
                    margin-top:14%;
                }
                #idea{
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
                .hidden{
                    display:none;
                    visibility:hidden; 
                }
            </style>
        </head>
    ";
    ?>
    <div id="header">
        <span class="header">
            Sorry, this tweak was not found...
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="header_minor">
        <span class="header_minor">
            Would you like to suggest it? or <a href="index.php" class="header_minor">Return home</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="idea">
        <form method="POST" action="idea.php" name="idea">
            <input type="text" name="idea" value="<?php echo $_POST['search']; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="hidden" class="hidden"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    exit();
}
```

?>

Comment: If you can, if there is an error to your site, please give a proper landing page for that (ex. 404 Not found) so that your visitors will not be confused what happened after the clicked to where they want to go, and also give them a proper link so that they can backtrack

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. It cannot interact with the browser the way you want.

Comment: @KevinAbelita I'm interacting with another site that's not my own. The page it goes to if the search result isn't found is just completely white. Code inspector doesn't recognize any code at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could have been better if you can call an api on that site so that you can interact easier with the external site.

I would do something like this:

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search_text = $_POST['search_field'];
    $location_url = "http://cydia.saurik.com/package/{$search_text}/";
    $content = @file_get_contents($location_url); // use this function to query on site
    if($content) {
        // redirect if it has a result
        header("Location: {$location_url}");
    } else {
        // will go here if query on external site is empty (blank)
        // create your own empty result page that says your search yielded no     results (your own page, redirect the user)
        // sample
        header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?noresults=1");
    }
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="search_field" class="" id="" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="search" class="" id="" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php if(isset($_GET['noresults'])): ?>
    <div class="yourdesign" style="display: block; width: 300px; border: 1px solid black;";>
        <h1>No results found</h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```